# Send line from file each time Lambda function is triggered [python]

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have search about this issue and couldn't find anything that would help me.

**EDITED**

The main idea is to, each time the lambda function is triggered by cloudwatch (everyday), choose a subsequent line from the text file that I get from a s3 bucket, that line will be attached to an e-mail.
The next time the lambda is triggered, the same will happen, but with the next line in the text file, and so on.

I have more or less an idea, using a for loop, my problem is how to, each time the function is triggered, select the next line in the text file.

Comment: A random line or in sequence?

Comment: @Marcin Ideally in sequence would be better.

Comment: Sorry, but your use-case is unclear. What do you mean by "choose a line"? Should it choose a subsequent line each day? Does the contents of the file ever change? How many lines are in the file? Have you considered doing it differently, such as storing messages in a FIFO queue and just grabbing the 'first' message each day, or storing one line per file in S3 and deleting a file each day?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited my question, I think it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read lines from your file in sequence, one lambda execution a day is one line, then you have to **keep track of those lines**. If its only once a day, you could use SSM Parameter Store for that. Each time your lambda executes, it would query SSM Parameter Store the the line number which was read previously.

Similarly, after successful dispatch of a line, the Lambda function would update the parameter in SSM Parameter Store.

The exact details depend on how big the file is, as this process can get progressively slow with time.

Comment: For now, it is a file with around 100 lines not too big, but might get bigger in the future.

Comment: @ack31 that's fine then. If it was in gigabytes or many megabytes it would be an issue.

Comment: how does this work? Can you explain me?

Comment: @ack31 I would suggest thing writing code for that yourself, if you encounter issues, making new and specific question for that.

Comment: I was asking about the SSM Parameter Store and how to use it...

Comment: @ack31 It would be good idea to check [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) on what is SSM Parameter Store and how to use it. Its too much to explain in SO's comments.

Comment: one question how will the ssm parameter store read the next line each time the lambda is executed?

Comment: @ack31 parameter store is to keep only line number which was previously read. Your lambda reads the value, get the line from the file which is `number+1`, and updates the value in the PS for next execution.